# How to get onclick event functionality without javascript?

Tags: html, css

I want that when I click this [watch trailer] button, I will see the trailer coming on the screen but without using on click (without javascript) using only CSS.

Also, When the video is seen there is a cross button. It should close the video on clicking but with CSS only.  I tried to do this using the checkbox CSS hack but it doesn't work.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.play {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.play img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.trailer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.trailer video {
  max-width: 900px;
  outline: none;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: invert(1);
  max-width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<a class="play"><img src="Images/play.png">Watch Trailer</a>
<div class="trailer">
  <video src="Images/Mulan-Official-Trailer.mp4" controls="true" autoplay="true"></video>
  <img src="Images/close.png" class="close">
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the checkbox code you tried and see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question (button bottom left of your question) and get the images/video working in the snippet. As A Haworth indicated too include the checkbox hack etc. you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the `onclick` event functionality without `javascript` by using the checkbox hack, Look at the code:

```css
#btn{
    display: none;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label::after {
  content: 'Close Trailer';
  display: none;
}

label > iframe {
  display: none;
}

#btn:checked + label > iframe {
    display: block !important;
}

#btn:checked + label > .play {
    display: none;
}

#btn:checked + label::after {
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="btn">
<label for="btn">
  <a class="play"><img src="Images/play.png">Watch Trailer</a>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YQ1vN_91KO0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</label>
```

Comment: are you sure this stops the playing video or just there eating browsers resources, only its not shown on browser??
#btn:checked + label > .play {
    display: none; 
}

Comment: @ndotie The answer is not as easy as a simple yes or no. But in my point of view video will be loaded but it is not visible to the user. To prevent loading video, instead of changing CSS, you can remove the video from HTML using JS.

Comment: @MubeenAhmad Thank you so much. You have solved a huge & tricky problem for me. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @HarshitJuneja It's nice helping you, please consider marking the answer as the correct one to help others having the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure IDs are unique for each item, otherwise this won't work

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

 :root {
  --close-size: 12px;
  --close-thickness: 2px;
  --close-color: #eeeeee;
  --close-hoverColor: #00adb5;
  --close-background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  --close-hoverBackground: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.play {
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.play::after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(data-title);
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #00adb5;
  color: #00adb5;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.trailer {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 80vw;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: center;
}

.play:checked+.trailer {
  display: flex;
}


/* Close Icon */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: var(--close-background);
  border-radius: 0 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.close:hover {
  background: var(--close-hoverBackground);
}

.close:before,
.close:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: var(--close-size);
  width: var(--close-thickness);
  background: var(--close-color);
  left: 45%;
  top: 30%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.close:hover:before,
.close:hover:after {
  background: var(--close-hoverColor);
}

.close:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}


/* Close Icon */

video {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <input id="trailer" class="play" type="checkbox" data-title="Watch Trailer!" />
  <div class="trailer">
    <div class="container">
      <video src="./trailer.mp4" poster="https://picsum.photos/350/200?random=1" controls="true"></video>
      <label for="trailer" class="close"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input id="trailer2" class="play" type="checkbox" data-title="Watch Trailer!" />
  <div class="trailer">
    <div class="container">
      <video src="./trailer.mp4" poster="https://picsum.photos/350/200?random=2" controls="true"></video>
      <label for="trailer2" class="close"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input id="trailer3" class="play" type="checkbox" data-title="Watch Trailer!" />
  <div class="trailer">
    <div class="container">
      <video src="./trailer.mp4" poster="https://picsum.photos/350/200?random=3" controls="true"></video>
      <label for="trailer3" class="close"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You have solved my problem perfectly by just using CSS only. Wonderful brain!! A huge thanks to you also.